# Why does pip install logger fail? Do I have a wrong setup?

Tags: python, logging, pip

I tried installing logger onto my computer using Python 3.0 but I get the following error:

`Collecting logger
Using cached logger-1.4.tar.gz (1.2 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [14 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 14, in 
File "C:\Users\atsahageas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
from setuptools.dist import Distribution
File "C:\Users\atsahageas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 35, in 
from ._importlib import metadata
File "C:\Users\atsahageas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_importlib.py", line 28, in 
disable_importlib_metadata_finder(metadata)
File "C:\Users\atsahageas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_importlib.py", line 17, in disable_importlib_metadata_finder
to_remove = [
File "C:\Users\atsahageas\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools_importlib.py", line 20, in 
if isinstance(ob, importlib_metadata.MetadataPathFinder)
AttributeError: module 'importlib_metadata' has no attribute 'MetadataPathFinder'
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`

[command return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3bXc.png)

Comment: That library hasn't been updated since 2013, you shouldn't use it. Use Python's inbuilt `logging` module onstead

Comment: The only thing that library contains is a logging configuration. If you really want to use it, then download manually and add to your project's source control.

Comment: You should install python 3.11.ob3.